# How can I connect to WMATA API?

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I am working on a project using WMATA (DC Metro) API and I need to retrieve some data such as stations names, pathing of two stations...
I have an API Key but I don't know to do the networking part. 
Should WMATA return an OAuthToken? How can I send a request?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should at least try using one of the code samples for each API call as it is available in 8 different languages at the bottom of each API page: https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/5476364f031f590f38092507/operations/5476364f031f5909e4fe330c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need OAuthToken or any Auth method, you just need to send your api_key at request header. There are a lot of example on wmata documentation. You can use Java examples as a reference for Kotlin.
[Look at the Java section bottom of this page](https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/54763629281d83086473f231/operations/5476362a281d830c946a3d6a?) and find this line:

```
request.setHeader("api_key", "{subscription key}");
```

Change

> {subscription key}

with your API Key